# Metric for affine transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Given a transformation matrix which contains a [rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions#Rotation_matrix) and translation: $$\begin{bmatrix}x'\\y'\\z'\\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}{\hat{\mathbf{u}}}_{x}&{\hat{\mathbf{v}}}_{x}&{\hat{\mathbf{w}}}_{x}&t_x\\{\hat {\mathbf{u}}}_{y}&{\hat{\mathbf{v}}}_{y}&{\hat{\mathbf{w}}}_{y}&t_y\\{\hat{\mathbf{u}}}_{z}&{\hat{\mathbf{v}}}_{z}&{\hat{\mathbf{w}}}_{z}&t_z\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\\1\end{bmatrix}$$

Can we define a general metric that describes how different two transformations are?

Such a metric exists for translations (distance function) and [rotations](http://www.boris-belousov.net/2016/12/01/quat-dist/#using-rotation-matrices), but can a generalised metric be obtained?

The purpose of this is to generate a single number that describes how similar two rigid bodies are, based on their position (transformation from the origin) and orientation.